# Angular 2 existing selector is not a known element

Tags: angular

I've tried every combination I can think of...

I'm trying to add a WYSIWYG editor into Angular 2.

but no matter what I do, I get 'editor is not a known element'

It is imported. it is declared. the selector exists.

I'm completely stumped.

EditorComponent

```
    import {NgModule, Component, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ContentChild, OnChanges, forwardRef} from '@angular/core';
    import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
    import {NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor} from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
        selector: 'header',
        template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
    })
    export class Header { }

    declare var Quill: any;

    export const EDITOR_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => EditorComponent),
        multi: true
    };

    @Component({
        selector: 'editor',
        templateUrl: "./editor.component.html",
        providers: [EDITOR_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
    })
    export class EditorComponent implements AfterViewInit, ControlValueAccessor {
        ...
        ...
    }
```

EditorModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { EditorComponent } from "./editor.component";


const declarables = [EditorComponent];

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterModule],
    exports: [declarables],
    declarations: [declarables],
})
export class EditorModule { }
```

app.module

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }        from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule }           from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule }          from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { routing,
         appRoutingProviders }  from './app.routing';


import { BlogModule }           from './blog/blog.module'

import { LoginComponent }       from './user/login.component';
import { NavComponent }         from './nav/nav.component';

import { DialogService }        from './dialog.service';

import { CKEditorModule }       from 'ng2-ckeditor';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CKEditorModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    routing,
    BlogModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    NavComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders,
    DialogService
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],

})
export class AppModule {
}
```

blog-edit.component

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostBinding,
         trigger, transition, animate,
         style, state } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import { BlogService }  from './blog.service';

import { BlogPost }   from '../model/blog-post';

import { EditorModule } from '../editor/editor.module'

@Component({
  templateUrl: './blog-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['blog-edit.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('routeAnimation', [
      state('*',
        style({
          opacity: 1,
          transform: 'translateX(0)',
        })
      ),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({
          opacity: 0,
          transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
        }),
        animate('0.2s ease-in')
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate('0.5s ease-out', style({
          opacity: 0,
          transform: 'translateY(100%)'
        }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class BlogEditComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

blog-edit.html

```
<editor></editor>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterModule],
    exports: [declarables],
    declarations: [declarables],
})
```

should be

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterModule],
    exports: declarables,
    declarations: declarables,
})
```

Comment: I got frustrated and just removed all references of the quill editor from the repo I was trying to use.  unless you might have some info on how to include the PrimeNg Editor instead, I'm just gonna delete this question

Comment: Well , that's another issue all together , but based on what i can see , you just had a syntax issue , you shouldn't put array inside array , doesn't make sense.

Comment: I agree. I just got pissed off. I bet you are right, I'll try it tomorrow

Comment: definitely a separate issue, but would you have a possible explanation for Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'CKEditorModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'?

Comment: I can't see CKEditorModule in your code , could you please update your code ?

Comment: Ok it's updated. Like I said, definitely separate issue, so don't go out of your way to help if you can't think of a reason for it right off the bat

Comment: I can't see anything is wrong in the code , but the package that you're using might not actually give you that module like that .
In order to make sure , you can console.log(CKEditorModule) after you're importing it to see what's inside it , it might be undefiend

Comment: If it's undefined , there might be a spelling error or something , make sure that package has CKEditorModule module and it's accessible like that.